# How to get CSV results without getting the column name (reading from jdbc request) in Jmeter

Tags: jmeter

How to get CSV results without getting the column name (reading from jdbc request) in Jmeter.

Jdbc request: select query is present it fetches the values to a variable.
-- under this we have JSR223 sampler which prints variable values to CSV file.

Thank u,
Mahadev S

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Add [JSR223 PostProcessor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_PostProcessor) as a child of the JDBC Request sampler
2. Put the following code into "Script" area:

   ```
   def result = vars.getObject('result') 
   def file = new File('foo.csv') 
   result.each { subresult ->
       subresult.values().each { value ->
           file << value << ','
       }
       file << System.getProperty('line.separator')
   }
   ```

   - replace `result` with what you have as the "Result variable name" in the JDBC Request sampler
   - replace `foo.csv` with the desired location of the CSV file
3. That's it, you will have the JDBC Request sampler output in form of table written to the CSV file. Check out [Debugging JDBC Sampler Results in JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/debugging-jdbc-sampler-results-jmeter) article for more information on working with JDBC result sets if needed.